# Selenium not clicking search box

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to have selenium to do the following:

1. Open a website
2. Click on the search box
3. Type "Seattle" in the search box
4. Select the first result from the suggested results
5. Hit Enter
6. Click on the new search box
7. Type "Chicago" in the new search box
8. Select the first result from the suggested results

I was able to get it to work until step 5, but I can't find a way to do the same tasks with a new search box in step 6.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://wego.here.com/'
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys('Seattle')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng_pristine"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng_pristine"))).send_keys('Chicago')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng_pristine"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Here's what the source page of the new search box looks like:

[image: 1]

This is the final result I want to see:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific scenario, to make a new search you should first clear the previous search state.
This should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://wego.here.com/'
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys('Seattle')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# clear the previous search results
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn_close"))).click()

#perform a new search
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys('Chicago')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**UPD**
For the edited question the answer is:
You are using a wrong locator.
This should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://wego.here.com/'
driver.get(url)

search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search")))
search_input.click()
search_input.send_keys('Seattle')
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

internal_search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#itinerary_item_input_0")))
internal_search_input.click()
internal_search_input.send_keys('Chicago')
internal_search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Actually, your code performs a new search instead of adding a departure information in the new search box. I edited a new image for your reference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I see. Looks like you didn't explain yourself clear enough or maybe I misunderstood you. Anyway, please try the updated answer.

Comment: Oh I see. That's how you access the id tag. Thanks a lot!